# How to scale a object using SKAction with repeat forever in Sprite Kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to continuously increase the height of a node on screen, to achieve that i created a `SKAction` to scale `Y`, and them apply a repeat forever in it, after the user touches the screen, here is the code:

```
var increaseSize = SKAction.scaleYTo(CGFloat(1.5), duration: 0.5)

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */
        //BRIDGE is a rectangular SKSpriteNode        

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
          bridge.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(increaseSize)) //BRIDGE is a rectangular SKSpriteNode   

        }
    }
```

Lets say bridge has a heigh of 100, after a touch on the screen, the height will be 150, which means the increaseSize action, is only running once.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`+ scaleXBy:y:duration:`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/scaleXBy:y:duration:):

```
let increaseSize = SKAction.scaleXBy(1, y: CGFloat(1.5), duration: 0.5)

... // the rest of your code (no need to change it)
```

The `scaleYTo` action will scale the node to a y size of 1.5 *once*, and then continue infinitely scaling it from 1.5 to 1.5 its original size, which does nothing at all. The `scaleXby:y:duration:` action will increase the relative scale, and so continue scaling it forever.

Comment: Thanks man, just one thing you need to set the x on scaleXBy to 1 instead of 0 ( 0 will make the node disappear), anyway as soon as i can i will accept your answer, thank again for the help!